# Social shares tracking in GA

Tags: google-analytics

This is pretty much covered topic for **original** FB/Twitter buttons. But what if I have my own "share on fb" button? Like this:

```
   <div id="fb_share"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=blah-blah">Share on FB</a></div>
```

so I've come up with the folloing solution:

```
var FBbtn = document.getElementById("fb_share");
    FBbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        ga('send', 'social', {
      'socialNetwork': 'facebook',
      'socialAction': 'share',
      'socialTarget': window.location
    });
    //console.log('tracked');
});
```

That is placed AFTER the Google Analytics code. 
Despite the fact it wont catch FB callback  - it is supposed to do the trick but for some reason I still cannot see any results in Analytics so the question is this: **will the solution actually work?** In fact it could be even like this I believe:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=blah-blah" onClick="ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook','Share',window.location.href);");">FB</a>
```

Comment: Your link is missing the id, so FBtn is not defined. Your second example should work, though.

Comment: Your second example spells the `href` attribute "hre". Make sure you're not doing that in your actual code.

Comment: yes-yes...sorry guys - both (the ID and the correct spelling of "href") are, of course, present. I have corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'share on Facebook' links causes the page to navigate (and not open a new window/tab).  When this navigation happens, most mainstream browsers cancel all pending HTTP requests for the current page and then navigates to the new page (fb.com)

In this scenario, one of the pending HTTP requests will be the GA event tracking call which will therefore never complete and never be received by the GA servers.

What you need to use is the GA hit callback functionality, this essentially cancels the native navigation (to FB), sends the tracking call and waits enough time for it to complete and then does a JavaScript redirection to the next page.

You should [read the google docs here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback)

In your case your event tracking function should be similar to this:

```
var FBbtn = document.getElementById("fb_share");
FBbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ga('send', 'social', {
    'socialNetwork': 'facebook',
    'socialAction': 'share',
    'socialTarget': window.location,
    'hitCallback': function(){
      window.location = this.href;
    }
  });
  //console.log('tracked');
  return false;
});
```

So I've made the following changes:

1. Added the hitCallback property to the event tracking call.  this is an anonymous function that is called once the GA servers have sent their response to the event tracking.
2. added a 'return false' statement which cancels the native functionality and then relies on the hitCallback function to do the navigating.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true anymore - Universal Analytics should (on browser which support this) use navigator.sendBeacon which is specifically designed to work even if the page is unloaded - see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport (I'm pointing this out for reference only - the hitCallback will support older browsers that haven't sendBeacon implemented and  thus is a good solution in any case).

Comment: Its a good point Eike, however I've seen this occur on client sites recently even using Chrome 45+ which should theoretically support navigator.beacon.  It's something I'll raise with the partners programme to see what the official status is.